# Distribution of maximum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables uniform on $(a,b)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3,\ldots$ i.i.d. $\mathrm{Unif}(a,b).$ $a<b$.

1) $Y_n = \max(X_1, X_2, X_3,\ldots,X_n)$, what is the method I should apply to find $Y_n$'s distribution?

2) Show that $Y_n$ converges to $b$ in probability.

3) What is the asymptotic distribution for $T=n(b-Y_n)$?

Could someone let me follow step by step? The proof is itself always highly appreciated; still, If I can point out which part I should revise it will be very fine. Actually, I got stuck with the maximum function and the uniform distribution at first.

Comment: $Y_n$ takes values in $(a,b)$ by definition. Now take $x\in(a,b)$ and consider $P(Y_n < x)$. Can you write the event $(Y_n < x)$ in terms of the $X_i$'s and use that they are iid?

Comment: P($Y_n<a$) isn't zero? Did I understand your comment right?

Comment: I have edited the comment - I of course thought about $P(Y_n < x)$. Excuse me.

Comment: Oh, I did not intend to confuse you. Then $P(Yn<x)=1- P(X_i=a).$

Comment: @Furrer Which idea should I derive next, then?

Comment: That is not correct. For $Y_n < x$, then every $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ has to be smaller than $x$, else the maximum won't be. Thus you should look at $P(X_1 < x,\ldots,X_n < x)$.

Comment: Then $1-P(X_i=x)$. My bad. I have just read it again.

Comment: You have to take any $X_i$ into account, not just one of them. We have that
P(Y_n<x)=P(X_1<x,\ldots,X_n<x).
Now you should use that the (X_i)'s are iid. What does this tell you about them?

Comment: Each $X_i$ has the same density, you mean?

Comment: And they are independent! When $Z$ and $W$ are independent, then $P(Z < z, W < w)=P(Z < z)P(W < w)$.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich Please no petty edits (what is wrong with being uniform on $(a,b)$ rather than on $[a,b]$, one wonders).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly, $Y_n$ is concentrated on $(a,b)$. Now take $x\in(a,b)$. Then

$P(Y_n < x) = P(X_1 \leq x, \ldots, X_n \leq x) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i \leq x) = \left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)^n$,

where we have used the definition of $Y_n$ and that the sequence $(X_i)$ is iid. Note: I don't really care about weak or strong inequalities due to continuity of the random variables.

To show convergence in probability, show that for any small $\epsilon>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(b-Y_n\geq \epsilon)=0$.

Now $P(Y_n \leq b - \epsilon) = \left(\frac{b - a - \epsilon}{b-a}\right)^n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, because $b - a - \epsilon < b - a$. Thus $Y_n$ converges to $b$ in probability.

Consider now $T_n = n (b - Y_n)$. We have for any $t >0$, that for $n$ sufficiently large,

$P(T_n \geq t) = P(Y_n \leq b - t/n) = \left(\frac{b-a - t/n}{b-a}\right)^n = \left(1 + \frac{-t/(b-a)}{n}\right)^n$,

thus $P(T_n \geq t) \to e^{-t/(b-a)}$ point-wise as $n\to\infty$. Hence $T_n$ converges in distribution to a $\exp(1/(b-a))$-distribution, so that is the asymptotic distribution of $T_n$. Note that this especially is a Weibull distribution, so the result is in accordance with general extreme value theory.

Comment: Thanks very much. I realized that the term IID is much more important than I usually skipped..!

Comment: I accepted your answer, of course. Can you add how can I construct the 95 confidence interval for "b" here?

Comment: You could take the 97,5 and 2,5 quantiles from the distribution $\exp(1/(b-a)$.

Comment: OK: It's really not that simple - depends on what you really want. I would suggest to construct the MLE of $b$ given observations $T_1,\ldots,T_n$ and then construct the confidence interval using quantiles from the exponential distribution with b substituted by its MLE.

Comment: I see. Here suppose $n=25, a=0, Y_n=5.3$, I need to construct the $b_^$ first.

Comment: I remember like $b_^$ is $((n-2)/n)*(1/x_(bar)))$. Should I use $Y_n$ as the sample mean?

Comment: Because $Y_n$ is the max value, I thought that there is different method to find the $b$ estimator for this case.